# Is the CiviCRM WhatsApp integration extension available now?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

Is the CiviCRM WhatsApp integration extension available now and how do you integrate CiviCRM with WhatsApp?

Comment: Curious, what does an extension like that do?

Answer (score 1):

User 'sluc23' created a 'whatsapp' extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/whatsapp but there is no content.  That sometimes happens when someone intends to publish an extension but doesn't get round to it.  I'd suggest asking on the ~extensions channel on https://chat.civicrm.org

Answer (score 0):

iXiam has self-funded and developed the [WhatsApp extension](https://www.civi-go.net/en/civigo-whatsapp) and it is near ready to be deployed to a few organizations. However, it requires a fair deal of setup and integrating with a provider to be able to send messages; it’s not just plug and play. With that said, we are open to publicly releasing the extension if there are parties that want to put funding behind it to cover the development cost and steps to making it public.

Feel free to get in touch with us for a demo: https://www.civi-go.net/en/contact.

Comment: Does the end-user need WA Business (which no one uses) or does s.he receive the message on his normal WA app but the organization needs a WA Business account or number to be able to access to the WA network?

Comment: Only the organization needs a WA business account.

Comment: great to know. I'm asking a few clients if they would be interested in adding WA to their CiviCRM.

Comment: Have you done any progress with the extension?